Zapier "Run Python Code" Error - Issue parsing dictionary
I'm just learning how to write python, but I've been using Zapier to start automating some tasks. (Also first time poster so hello everyone!)
I have the following data:
countries = [
    {"Country_Num": 1, "Country_Name": "United States"},
    {"Country_Num": 2, "Country_Name": "United Kingdom"},
    {"Country_Num": 3, "Country_Name": "Canada"},
    {"Country_Num": 4, "Country_Name": "Germany"},
    {"Country_Num": 5, "Country_Name": "France"},
    {"Country_Num": 6, "Country_Name": "Australia"},
    {"Country_Num": 7, "Country_Name": "Japan"},
    {"Country_Num": 8, "Country_Name": "Brazil"},
    {"Country_Num": 9, "Country_Name": "India"},
    {"Country_Num": 10, "Country_Name": "South Africa"}
]


And I'm trying to turn this data into something useable in Zapier, so that I can add that data into a GoogleSheet.
Therefore, I'm using the Zapier step called "Run Python in Code by Zapier" and it allows me assign the input data above as "countries"
Now, I'm trying to use code to turn the data into two outputs that I can use using the following script:
# Accessing the input data which is provided as 'countries'
countries_data = input_data['countries']

# Initializing lists to hold country numbers and names
country_nums = []
country_names = []

# Iterating over each country in the input data
for country in countries_data:
    # Appending the country number and name to their respective lists
    country_nums.append(country["Country_Nums"])
    country_names.append(country["Country_Names"])

# Preparing the output to include both lists
output = {'Country_Nums': country_nums, 'Country_Names': country_names}

return output

However, whenever I try to test the code, I get the following error:
Failed to create a run python in Code by Zapier
Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 18, in the_function TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Any help would be appreciated!!
UPDATE: In response to @John Gordon:
I tried to print the output, and I get the following in replit
(PS: I used replit to test code because that's all I'm familiar with - please tell me if there's another way that you want me to test):

UPDATE2: I think I might know what's going on now. If you look at the Zapier screenshot, it says that the data provided is treated as a string.

Any ideas on what I need to do to convert the data from a string to an actual list with dictionaries?

Show us the actual contents of countries_data.

They did, the contents are 'countries' provided above.

The given error would not be possible if that were true.  So the actual data must be different.

Please show us the actual output of print(countries_data).

@JohnGordon I just added Update and Update2.
I modified the countries_data variable to work without the Zapier syntax of input_data['keyName']

It seems that you've made a typo when assigning 'Country_Nums'. It should be 'Country_Num'. Running your code as a basic Python file using the countries data as countries_data provides an error because of that typo.
Fixing it means the code runs as normal - when I print output to the terminal, it writes
{'Country_Num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'Country_Name': ['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Canada', 'Germany', 'France', 
'Australia', 'Japan', 'Brazil', 'India', 'South Africa']}

Hopefully this helps! Since I don't use Zapier, I'm not sure if the problem will be the exact same, but from how you've detailed the functions of Zapier, it should be very similar.
Fixed code:
# Accessing the input data which is provided as 'countries'
countries_data = input_data['countries']

# Initializing lists to hold country numbers and names
country_nums = []
country_names = []

# Iterating over each country in the input data
for country in countries_data:
    # Appending the country number and name to their respective lists
    country_nums.append(country["Country_Num"])
    country_names.append(country["Country_Name"])

# Preparing the output to include both lists
output = {'Country_Num': country_nums, 'Country_Name': country_names}

return output


They did make a typo on the key name Country_Nums vs Country_Num, but that is not the cause of the given error.

The given script actually only has 17 lines as far as I can see, so I'm not sure about anything else I can do to fix stuff. Thanks for the feedback, though - I appreciate it! Leaving the answer up because fixing a typo is really the only thing I can see is fixable without more code or information.

@Redz thanks for catching that typo! But yeah - it still gives me the same error.
Also, I'm not sure why Zapier returns the wrong lines when talking about the error.

What additional information can I provide to help?
There is this link where Zapier provides some documentation on it.
https://help.zapier.com/hc/en-us/articles/8496326417549-Use-Python-code-in-Zaps#h_01H9FNT4XP8QD8XR29S5WZ382Z
They say that it must be JSON serializable. Could that be the issue?

@GarlonYau The error mentions that the issue is on line 18 in the file named  - since the code you provided was only 17 lines, I'm not sure if the error is even in this code. Maybe it's in a completely different file?
